# Powershell Automation for Services

Tags: windows, winforms, powershell

I have 100+ servers for which I have to check services. On almost 5 servers we have identical services. Each boxes contains min of 3 services.
I am importing content from the file I saved in a location. For Server name I am good. For Service I have saved like service_starting_name* in column under the file like below

```
AA*
BB*
CC*
```

Below is the code. Is this good idea for automation as per below code ?

```
$ServerName = Get-Content "Absolutepath"
$Service = Get-Content "Absolutepath"
foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {

        write-host $($server)
        Get-Service -ComputerName $Server $Service


}
```

Also , How can we do a better display like, without printing the service name ?
Suppose, In Server X , 5 services , so if all services are running just print all good on that server.

I tried using if conditions but as there are many services , it is printing multiple times because for for each loop .
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with various things..
For testing I use localhost, when you try:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -DisplayName *sophos*
```

You get:
[image]

```
(Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -DisplayName *sophos*).count
```

*result 10*

```
(Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -DisplayName *sophos*).Status -contains "stopped"
```

*result True*

So if you use:

```
if (!((Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -DisplayName *sophos*).Status -contains stopped)) { Write-Host "Localhost: All ok" }
```

Or:

```
if (!(Get-Service -ComputerName $server -DisplayName $Service | select status | where {$_.Status -like "Stopped"})) { Write-Host "$($Server): All OK" }
```

You can use various checks for services "stopping" or whatever..
The above are just to give you ideas!

Hope it helps.

Comment: For the last solution you provided , The output(All ok) is coming same for all the servers for all remote machines , whether services are stopped or running.

Comment: 1st you need to change the ServerName to Server:: foreach ($Server in $ServerName) { if (!((Get-Service -ComputerName $Server $Service).Status -contains "Stopped")) { Write-Host "Localhost: All ok" } }.  Also this searches just the service "name". If the name is not relevant the DisplayName might be better.. For me the difference is 12 services from "DisplayName"  to 8 services returned from the "name" query.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zYbMjUSS

For the local computer I can run .Status but for the remote one its not working, As I have to check for all the remote boxes for all their services.

Comment: can you view the services from Get-Service -ComputerName xxxx ? If you get access denied then make sure the shell you are using has domain admin rights. The get-service does not accept credentials, you can use instead (if needed) Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $Computer -Filter "Name='Something'".

Comment: I can get -services without passwords. Its working fine.

get-service Service_Name* 

If i am doing this in loop its giving all server outputs.

Comment: From PSv5 when I try: (Get-Service -ComputerName XXXX -DisplayName $test).Status 
I get: 
Running
Stopped
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Stopped
But from PSv2 (not my workstation but from the server) I get nothing...

Comment: For me Machines are v2 and v3

Comment: Any idea how to go with get-wmiobject , as i have to use file for the server as well as for the service, May be it work ?

Comment: Try this instead:
if (!(Get-Service -ComputerName $server -DisplayName $Service | select status | where {$_.Status -like "Stopped"})) { Write-Host "$($Server): All OK" }

Comment: It's Working . I just added few more lines  to it as per my original code. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know :)
I updated the answer above (mark it as answer if you can)